# Unbind parent event temporarily

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I have a div that has an event to load a message, however within that div is a radio button. What I'm trying to do is stop the div to load a message if the radio button within that div is selected. What I've tried is to detect if the radio button is selected, and do something if so, else display the message. The problem is, its not doing what it should. **I believe this is because it never reaches the checked status for a radio button because I hit the parent div load message first.**

Here's the code I have thus far:

```
function loadMessage(messageId,id)
{   
    var radioId = 'c' + id;
        if($('#'+radioId).is(':checked')){
    
    } else {
        if(currentMail != messageId) {
            currentMail = messageId;
            var loc = 'ajax.php?ax=fetch-message&mx='+messageId;
            messageContainer.load(loc);
            $("#right").show();
            expandRight()
        } else {
            currentMail = "";
            minimizeRight(true);
            $("#right").hide();
        }
    }
}`
```

Here's the html:

```
 <div onclick="loadMessage('5ca477dd1d',4152)" class="row2 mail-message">
 <input type="checkbox" id="c4152" name="c4152">
 </div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `$('<selector>').unbind();` unbinds all the events attached to the the element.Also check this out http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-bind-and-unbind-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First thing** is that it is **checkbox** not **radio**.

And I think to solve your problem remove the `checkbox` from the `div` because when you `click` on `div` your `checkbox is automatically clicked`

Try it like,

```
<div onclick="loadMessage('5ca477dd1d',4152)" class="row2 mail-message">
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="c4152" name="c4152">
```

**Alternatively,** you can `bind` the `click event` to the `checkbox` rather than that of `div element`

like,

```
<div class="row2 mail-message">
    <input onclick="loadMessage('5ca477dd1d',4152)"  type="checkbox" id="c4152" name="c4152">
</div>
```

Also, from your `code` I can't understand about `messageContainer`.

Comment: this is how the designer gave me the mockups. is there no way to do this using the html i provided?